# One-One, Simple And Jordan Curves

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, curves

I want to be sure with the definitions.

A curve $\gamma(t)=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ which is $1-1$ is simple (as it does not have $2$ images for the same $t$)

A curve which is simple and closed is a jordan curve? but if it is closed so it is not $1-1$ as $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ for $\gamma:I\to \mathbb{R}^n $where $I=[a,b]$

Comment: A simple closed curve in $\Bbb R^2$, also called a Jordan curve (because of the "obvious" but hard-to-prove Jordan Curve Theorem), is a homeomorphic image of the circle $S^1=\{(\cos t,\sin t): t\in \Bbb R\}.$... If $\gamma: S^1\to C\subset \Bbb R^2$ is continuous and $1$-to-$1$ and onto, then $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks, I have yet to fully undersantd there are 3 definitions 1-1, simple and closed, does $1-1$ implies simple? meaning that a 1-1 does not cut itself (else from the point where it "close" let say $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ in $[a,b]$)

Comment: You can map $[a,b]$ to $S^1$ by $f(x)=( \cos y,\sin y)$ where $y=2\pi \frac {x-a}{b-a}$ (i,e, bend the interval into  a circle, and then map g:S^1\to C $ homeomorphically .... The "closed" in this context does not mean topologically closed.  It means that the map  $gf: [a,b]\to C$ $ satisfies $gf(a)=gf(b).$  Simple means that $gf(x)\ne gf(y)\ne gf(a)$ for $a<x<y<b. $